# Jquery Text Removing entire HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a page with jquery. I want to change a text in a html dom. But when I'm trying to do this its removing entire html code under the dom. 
You can check the jsfiddle here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/msxpwr5p/

**html markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Edit Profile
        <div class="broadcast">
            <button id="button1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn">   </i>button1</button>
       </div>
       <div class="broadcast">
           <button id="button2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button2</button>
       </div>
    </h1>
</div>
```

**JSfile**

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(e){
$(".page-header").text("another text");
});
```

I just want to change the **Edit Profile** text. I don't want to remove my buttons. Whats wrong with my code?

I know I have inserted some `div` into my `h1`, It is intentionally. I want to know if there are any solutions to this type of situation? 
suppose I create a

```
<div id="hello">
    Hello
    <a href=#></a>
    <button>text</button>
<div>
```

In this situation if I want to change the "hello" text. What should I do?

Comment: So move your divs outside of your h1: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/msxpwr5p/1/

Comment: yes, because you are using the h1 as container, which you shouldn't do.

Comment: Never ever put a div inside a h1.

Comment: I have edited my question again. please have a look..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(e){
   $('h1').contents().first()[0].textContent='another Title';
});
```

Check the output at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3n7t72z/)

Comment: Thanks for your expert solution. but as a beginner i'm feeling like in jQuery text() and html() has no useful difference. text() should find the text on the selected dom and leave the other html.

Answer (score 3):

Close your `h1` in the **correct** place:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Edit Profile</h1>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="createchannel" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>Create Channel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="listchannel" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>List Channel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your h1 was open on almost the whole div.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1c2yLern/)

Answer (score 3):

Your changing the text of the `h1` tag with JQuery, in your html your  tag is enclosing everything

```
<div class="container">
  *Starts here*<h1 class="page-header">Edit Profile
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button2</button>
  </div>
  </h1>*ends here*
</div>
```

What you want is to close the header after `Edit Profile`, so change it to this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-header">Edit Profile</h1>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in my situation i cant close it. I have to leave the markup as it is. is there any way to catch the text only and change it in jquery? i have edited my question for better explanation. please have a look.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have put the answer here and you can check the code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3n7t72z/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (without any change in your HTML codes)

```
$("#createchannel").on('click', function(e){
    var text = $(".page-header")[0].firstChild;
    text.textContent = "another text";
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/msxpwr5p/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-header"><span id='under_header'>Edit Profile<span>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button2</button>
  </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer has appeared in the low quality posts queue. Please add an explanation on how this addresses the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable via javascript would be possible with your current markup, but I'd recommend simply closing your H1 tag and adjusting your styling on the buttons accordingly

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-header">Edit Profile</h1>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="broadcast">
  <button id="button2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>button2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it with your current markup using this script:

```
$("#createchannel").on('click', function(e){
  $(".page-header")[0].firstChild.data = "Create Channel";
});
```

Here's the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/msxpwr5p/3/

This is definitely a fragile solution though, if your markup changes this could break easily.

Comment: I wanted to know is it possible in jquery in current markup? I have edited my question for better understanding. please have a look

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer to use your existing markup.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it has been said in the comment section, I'll keep in mind that you can't change the place of the closing tag. You can detach your element from the DOM before changing the text :

```
$("#createchannel").on('click', function(e){
    var $child = $(".page-header").children().detach();
    $(".page-header").text("Create Channel").append($child);
});
```

Detaching them will allow you to keep a reference on you element while removing them from the DOM. When using `.text()`, it empty the targeted DOM element and change its text. So right after you change the text, you can append the detached elements.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/msxpwr5p/4/

Comment: Pretty Nice tricks. Thanks for your suggestion. But i think jQuery should concern about this. As a minimum common sense anyone can expect text() function will find the text and effect on the text. and html() function can change the entire html on the selected dom. the main difference between html and text should be this. But right now text and html function doesn't have much difference rather than the data type. one treat the code as a code and another treat the code as string. nothing else. As a professional don't you think this should be fixed by jQuery? @karl-Andre Gagnon

Comment: @Shobdo In an ideal world, yes, but in a pratical world, it will not be possible, well not right now. There's too many variant to do what you want. In this specific case, this solution work, but what would happen if you had an inline node between the text? `<p>This line <span>will be</span> weird.</p>` for example. It will be hard to know where to stop right? Using this technique with `"Like Yoda, I"` as argument would result to : `<p>Like Yoda, I <span>will be</span></p>`. There is some limitation in JavaScript. The main advantage of using `text` is that it encode in HTML.